# Convert datetime format to ISO8601 format in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a table `IMAGEDATA` in which the column VALUE stores datetime format in `en-US` (for ex. `06/08/2012 02:10:36 p.m`.). I need to convert the `datetime` format to `ISO8601` format (ex. `2012-08-22T13:10:39`) for all the rows that are currently in the table. I'm novice in these topics. Could you please me some better approach it will be more helpful.Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434481/how-to-convert-date-to-iso-8601-in-sql-server/16434596#16434596

Answer (score 1):

Internally Datetime values are stored as `2 integers` . They are not stored in the specific format in which they are inserted .In order to convert to `8601` format try the below code

```
Declare @date datetime
set @date = '06/08/2012 02:10:36 '
Select convert(varchar(30),@date,126)
```